Microsoft outlook client can't do cmd + ` window switching
I've got a new Mac and have installed Version 16.87.2 Microsoft Outlook
However, while other apps allow ⌘ + ` to switch windows of the same app, Outlook doesn't!
Is there any fix to solve this?
I found posts on StackExchange to remap app shortcuts but I kinda need to know the name of the command in order to modify the existing outlook client shortcuts.
Any ideas?

Installed Version 16.87.2 of what?

just updated. Sorry!

I have an older version of Microsoft Outlook (v16.77 from September 2023), so I'm not sure if it happens on newer versions, but the Command+``` works for me? Obviously this won't work if Microsoft Outlook runs everything from a single window? I.e. if I'm drafting/viewing an email in the main window, it won't do anything but if I'm drafting an email in a separate window the keyboard shortcut will allow you to switch windows

It turned out to be a temporary issue. It has gone now, strangely.
